# Strange behavior of Object.defineProperty() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was playing with below javascript code. Understanding of `Object.defineProperty()` and I am facing a strange issue with it. When I try to execute below code in the browser or in the VS code the output is not as expected whereas if I try to debug the code the output is correct

When I debug the code and evaluate the profile I can see the `name & age` property in the object
But at the time of output, it only shows the `name` property

```js
//Code Snippet 
let profile = {
  name: 'Barry Allen',
}

// I added a new property in the profile object.
Object.defineProperty(profile, 'age', {
  value: 23,
  writable: true
})

console.log(profile)
console.log(profile.age)
```

Now expected output here should be

```
{name: "Barry Allen", age: 23}
23
```

but I get the output as.
Note that I am able to access the `age` property defined afterwards. 
I am not sure why the `console.log()` is behaving this way.

```
{name: "Barry Allen"}
23
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You should set `enumerable` to `true`. In `Object.defineProperty` its `false` by default. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description).

> **enumerable**
>   `true` if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object.
>   **Defaults to false.**

Non-enumerable means that property will not be shown in `Object.keys()` or `for..in` loop neither in console

```js
let profile = {
    name: 'Barry Allen',
}

// I added a new property in the profile object.

Object.defineProperty(profile , 'age', {
    value: 23,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true
})
console.log(profile)
console.log(profile.age)
```

All the properties and methods on `prototype` object of built-in classes are non-enumerable. Thats is the reason you can call them from instance but they don't appear while iterating.

To get all properties(including non-enumerable)[`Object​.get​OwnProperty​Names()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)
.

```js
let profile = {
    name: 'Barry Allen',
}

// I added a new property in the profile object.

Object.defineProperty(profile , 'age', {
    value: 23,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false
})
for(let key in profile) console.log(key) //only name will be displayed.

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(profile)) //You will se age too
```

Comment: I didn't knew about this, but when I checked by running the local code in browser, it shows up perfectly (in spite of explicitly specifying `enumerable` to false).

Comment: @randomSoul I can't get what you mean.

Comment: See - https://pasteboard.co/IaOxMqB.png . I did not set `enumerable` to true for `age`, but still it is shown.

Comment: @randomSoul See the comments of the answer of certain performance.

Comment: @randomSoul In Chrome console, you should see unenumerable properties colored a little bit transparent.

Comment: @YongQuan - Yes, after expanding the object I can notice the difference and setting `enumerable` true explicitly will make it look brighter. But, the property is still `visible` and is not completely hidden as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @randomSoul That's a debugging feature, not a language feature. If you change the example to use `JSON.stringify` it will behave consistently, and omit the non-`enumerable` properties.

Comment: @MikeCaron - Thanks

Answer (score 25):

By default, properties you define with `defineProperty` are not *enumerable* - this means that they will not show up when you iterate over their `Object.keys` (which is what the snippet console does). (Similarly, the `length` property of an array does not get displayed, because it's non-enumerable.)

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> **enumerable**
>
> true if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object.
>
> **Defaults to false.**

Make it enumerable instead:

```js
//Code Snippet 
let profile = {
  name: 'Barry Allen',
}

// I added a new property in the profile object.
Object.defineProperty(profile, 'age', {
  value: 23,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true
})

console.log(profile)
console.log(profile.age)
```

The reason you can see the property in the [logged image](https://pasteboard.co/IaOxMqB.png) is that Chrome's console will show you non-enumerable properties as well - **but the non-enumerable properties will be slightly greyed-out**:

[image]

See how `age` is grey-ish, while `name` is not - this indicates that `name` is enumerable, and `age` is not.

Comment: Someone give this https://pasteboard.co/IaOxMqB.png Its showing `age` property in chrome console. Can you please explain that? Does chrome console works differently?

Comment: Yes, that's a Chrome console behavior - it'll show you *all* properties, including non-enumerable ones, see edit. The non-enumerable properties (like `age` and `__proto__`) will be slightly greyed out.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you use".defineProperty" method of object. You should better define all the properties of the descriptor. Because if you don't define other property descriptor then it assumes default values for all of them which is false. So your console.log checks for all the enumerable : true properties and logs them.

```
//Code Snippet 
let profile = {
  name: 'Barry Allen',
}

// I added a new property in the profile object.
Object.defineProperty(profile, 'age', {
  value: 23,
  writable: true,
  enumerable : true,
  configurable : true
})

console.log(profile)
console.log(profile.age)
```