# Why don't we see 'o's 'b' property when we log 'o'?

Tags: javascript

Looking at the example given on this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```js
const o = {a: 0};

Object.defineProperty(o, 'b', { get: function() { return this.a + 1; } });

console.log(o.b) // Runs the getter, which yields a + 1 (which is 1)

console.log(o)
```

Why, when I log `o`, why do I:
Not see it in `node.js`?
See it but it's greyed out in Chrome?

Comment: I see it in Firefox.

Comment: inside the get function, 'this' is window ; so use 'o'

Comment: @TilakMaddy: That's not correct.

Comment: The property is not enumerable.

Comment: How the console works is not standardized. Difference between environments is to be expected, especially for more "exotic" things like getters.

Comment: It is shown in Chrome too, you just have to expand the object structure

Comment: See: [Strange behavior of Object.defineProperty() in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55757089/5648954)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you add `enumerable: true` to the `defineProperty()` options object, you'll see it. By default, properties added with `.defineProperty()` are *not* enumerable.

Some console environments might choose to show all properties, others don't.

Comment: @FelixKling well the snippet above, in the "console" Stack Overflow provides, does not include "b" in the output unless it's made enumerable. You're right, it's up to the console, but more practically in programming it's a significant difference.