# Why is Angular's PUT sending an empty body?

Tags: angular

I created an object and filled it with some properties using `Object.defineProperty` then fed that object as an argument for Angular's `http.put` but for some reason the back end is receiving an empty body.

```
      let newData = {};

      Object.defineProperty(newData, 'newTitle', {
        value: this.taskForm.value.title,
      });

      Object.defineProperty(newData, 'newDescription', {
        value: this.taskForm.value.description,
      });

      Object.defineProperty(newData, 'newSubtasks', {
        value: this.taskForm.value.subtasks,
      });

      this.http.editTask(this.taskId, newData).subscribe();
```

### editTask implementation

```
  editTask(taskId: string, data: any) {
    return this.http.put(`http://localhost:3000/edittask/${taskId}`, data);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange behavior of Object.defineProperty() in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757089/strange-behavior-of-object-defineproperty-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not prefer to `Object.defineProperty` but this will solved your problem.

```js
// code

          let newData = {};

          Object.defineProperty(newData, 'newTitle', {
            value: 1,
          });

          Object.defineProperty(newData, 'newDescription', {
            value: 2,
          });

          Object.defineProperty(newData, 'newSubtasks', {
            value: 3,
          });

          const data = {};
          Object.getOwnPropertyNames(newData).forEach(key => data[key] = newData[key]);
          this.http.editTask(this.taskId, data).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Try JSON.stringify()**

```
this.http.editTask(this.taskId, JSON.stringify(newData)).subscribe();
```